# ¿Cómo eliminar caracteres codificados de un archivo generado en PDF usando jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, html

Usando la librería [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) y siguiendo este [código de muestra](http://jsfiddle.net/xzz7n/1/) tomado de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19290964), estoy trabajando en un desarrollo usando HTML y javascript para generar un archivo PDF.

El contenido del archivo PDF es el código HTML de esta [página de prueba](https://mega.nz/#!f0N10JwS!Cboe70hGajD1olLMsLtOjOQM15hxQfA6kJCysYlqYLg)<sup>1</sup> que puede descargar para revisar su contenido.

Al abrir el archivo en el navegador y al seleccionar el enlace de descarga; el archivo PDF es descargado en la carpeta de "Descargas"<sup>2</sup>, pero el resultado contiene algunos caracteres codificados:

Éste es un fragmento del archivo HTML:

```
<div class="TituloPagina">
     CONTRATO INDIVIDUAL DE TRABAJO A TÉRMINO FIJO INFERIOR A UN AÑO CELEBRADO ENTRE
     COMPAÑÍA (A). Y FUTURO EMPLEADO (B) –SALARIO ORDINARIO.
</div>
```

El caracter `–` se muestra codificado en el PDF así: `þÿ`

He intentado:

- Colocar la propiedad `UTF-8` en el archivo HTML.
- Guardar el archivo HTML [como se indica en la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14832993), *pero en este caso*, no considero que el problema se encuentre en el archivo HTML de muestra, sino en el **resultado de la conversión a PDF**.
- Cambiar la etiqueta `meta` así: `<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />`; lo que ocasiona que el archivo HTML pierda la codificación de los caracteres tales como `ñ` acentos, etc.

Pero no hay ninguna diferencia en los archivos PDF generados.

**¿Cómo eliminar caracteres codificados de un archivo generado en PDF usando jsPDF?**

---

<sup>1</sup> He creado este archivo de prueba, ya que el desarrollo real contiene información confidencial.

<sup>2</sup> La ruta de la descarga varía según la configuración de cada usuario en su navegador de preferencia.

Comment: Has intentado con `iso-8859-1`

Comment: @jasilva, honestamente, no; tampoco conozco cómo implementarlo.

Comment: Perdon por no ser mas claro, cambiar `UTF-8` por `iso-8859-1`

Comment: @jasilva, acabo de hacer la prueba, y me genera mas elementos codificados: `<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />` Si gusta, puede dar click al archivo de prueba de mi pregunta e intentarlo "es un archivo HTML" :) gracias por su ayuda y estoy atento a las respuestas.

Comment: Parece ser un bug.  Lo aconsejable es evitar los caracteres con código > 255. Por ejemplo, ese guión ("–", U+2013) cambiarlo por el guión ASCII "-", etc.

Comment: @angus, gracias. He considerado generar el archivo sin esos caracteres, tendré que consultar con la persona encargada _"la persona que provee el template de los archivos a generar"_ para así hacer el ajuste en el código HTML. Estoy respondiendo a su respuesta con un comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo indica que es un bug en el plugin "fromHTML". Una solución puede ser evitar usar caracteres con código mayor a 255 (restringirse a los caracteres en [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)).

La otra es usar tu propia jsPDF, cambiando [esta línea](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/plugins/from_html.js#L819), donde dice:

```
pdfEscape(text)
```

por

```
pdfEscape(text, { 'noBOM': true, 'autoencoding': true })
```

Una tercera solución: mapear los caracteres al generar el vector de 8 bits.

Manteniendo el cambio en la llamada a `pdfEscape`, en el módulo principal, después de [esta línea](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js#L602), poner

```
if (ch == 0x2013) ch = 150;
else if (ch == 0x2014) ch = 151;
```

Hacer lo mismo con los caracteres de [esta tabla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout) cuando difieran su valor Unicode con su valor en el charset (son los de las filas "8_" y "9_").

(*Disclaimer:* parece lo correcto pero no lo he probado.)

Comment: Acabo de hacer la prueba, pero los caracteres no los codifica: **los desaparece.**

Comment: ¿Qué prueba? Puse dos alternativas.

Comment: la segunda sugerencia: cambiar la llamada a la función así: `pdfEscape(text, { 'noBOM': true, 'autoencoding': true })`. _Una opción puede ser_ la restricción del uso de caracteres, pero quien genera los documentos / archivos HTML es otra persona (cliente). Por lo tanto, restringir los caracteres es una solución opcional. Quisiera conocer si existe otra solución para evitar dicha restricción.

Comment: Ajá. Veo que el PDF se codifica con WinAnsiEncoding, no importa los caracteres que contenga. Entonces sí, la segunda alternativa sólo evita el "þÿ", y los caracteres fuera de Windows-1252 no se dibujan. La única solución es cambiarlos. Agrego algo en el mensaje al respecto.

Comment: he realizado la prueba de indica en su respuesta, la he aceptado porque es una solución alternativa, Desafortunadamente, tengo otro inconveniente, pero parece que jsPDF no puede solucionar correctamente el requerimiento en el que estoy trabajando.
Gracias por su ayuda.